# Nginx proxy pass converting %7c to pipe '|'

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

**Problem-** I have a url say `https://example.com/app/something%7Csomething` but when i pass it via proxy pass in nginx to make it look like `https://example.com/api/something%7Csomething`, it changes the %7c to a '|' and throws an error.

**Nginx conf-**

```
location /api/ {
      proxy_pass https://example2.com/;
  }
```

How should I prevent this change?